# List becomes null when accessed in own class after being filled in child class

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I am trying to fill a list of Gameobjects that I spawn every X seconds. This list is instantiated in one class (`PickUpWeapons`) as such:

```cs
//list of weapons spawned over the course of the game
public List<GameObject> weaponsToPickUp = new List<GameObject>();
```

And in my class where I spawn weapons (`SpawnObjects`), I fill this list as such:
`PickUpWeapons pickUp; //reference to pickUpWeapons class`

```cs
//instanciate
private void Start() {
    //generate instance of the pool
    objectPooler = ObjectPooler.Instance;

    pickUp = gameObject.AddComponent<PickUpWeapons>();  //instanciate the class
    //pickUp.weaponsToPickUp = new List <GameObject>();
}

private void FixedUpdate() {
    //only spawn objects if it is time
    if (Time.time > nextSpawnTime) {
        //update next spawn time
        nextSpawnTime = Time.time + spawnRateWeapons;
        //where we spawn the weapons
        float randomXPos = Random.Range(- xMax, xMax);
        whereToSpawn = new Vector2(randomXPos, transform.position.y);
        //generate object
        GameObject bullet = ObjectPooler.Instance.SpawnFromPool("Bullet", whereToSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
        //freeze its position on X only
        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionX;

        //add weapon generated as a potentially picked up weapon
        pickUp.weaponsToPickUp.Add(bullet);
        Debug.Log(pickUp.weaponsToPickUp.Count);
    }
}
}
```

In this class `(SpawnObjects) pickUp.weaponsToPickUp` is not empty and the Log does indicate an increase in size of `weaponsToPickUp`. However, back in `PickUpWeapons` class, this list is now empty.

Does anyone know what I could do to solve this please?

Comment: How do you check that the list is empty inside the `PickUpWeapons` object instantiated this way?

Comment: Are you sure it becomes **`null`**? This would mean your list gets destroyed somewhere ... I'ld rather guess the reference to the `pickUp` itself is `null` ... could you add your exact error you get?

Comment: When you say "back in PickUpWeapons class, this list is now empty", what do you mean?  You've added to the weaponsToPickUp list of the instance attached to your SpawnObjects object.  The list is not static, though, so the list in other instances of PickUpWeapons won't automatically be populated.